# How to fix textbox position on the screen

Tags: javascript, textbox, positioning

I am implementing a chat system in my web app and I am showing the message list (where new messages will be appended below) and a message box where the user can type in their messages.

[image]

The current issue I am facing is that the message box gets pushed down the screen as I add new messages to the list (appended to bottom of last row).

How can I fix the position of the message box on the screen so that it doesn't get pushed down?

To clarify, the message box will always be below the last message in the list. This means that I would need the page to auto scroll so that the message box will always stay in position i.e. in the center of the screen

Comment: What are you aiming at? If it doesn't come down to fit the screen, eventually it will obstruct a message. You could try with position:fixed or position:absolute, but if you don't explain better what you try to accomplish I can't offer much help

Comment: Hi @PabloMescher, thanks for your note. I edited my question to make it clearer. The box will always be below the last message, hence I would need the whole page to scroll or adjust so that the message box stays in the same position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've not shared any markup, I've made one demo of mine...So inorder to stop your input box pushed down, you need to use `overflow-y: scroll;` on your message box and give it a fixed height to it like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NRuaY/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
</div>
<input type="text" />​
```

CSS

```
.container {
height: 200px; 
width: 200px; 
background-color: #ff0000; 
overflow-y: scroll;
}​
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! How can I ensure that the default is to scroll to the bottom so that the bottom message is always visible?

Comment: you welcome :) and you need to use javascript/jquery to accomplish that :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite understand the exact question.

If you are looking to fix the message box to certain position in the window regardless of other controls' positions, you can do something like this:

```
#msgboxContainer
{
  position:absolute;
  left:10px; 
  bottom:20;
}
```